# If I add apple cider vinegar to a cleanser with a pH level of 7, will the pH level of it drop?

Tags: acid-base

I am thinking about adding apple cider vinegar to my Physiogel Dermo cleanser which has the following ingredients:
Aqua, PEG-75, Cetearyl Alcohol, Disodium Phosphate, Sodium Cocoyl Isethionate, Methylparaben, Citric Acid, Butylparaben, Propylparaben, Parfum.

Let's say I mix 1tablespoon of apple cider vinegar to a 150ml physiogel bottle. Will the ph level of it drop and will it syill be safe to use on facial skin?

Comment: If it will work on your skin is a medical question which we won't answer. We're chemists, not medical doctors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question consists of two parts, I'll reply in two parts, too.

- Regarding the cleanser alone:  among the consititutents you list, it already contains *both* one, that is an acidic component (citric acid), and one that is basic (disodium phosphate).  It is by intent that the two are present simultaneously in the cleanser, as they -- altogether with water (here: named aqua) -- form a [buffer solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_solution).  This is a way to tune the acidity, the pH value of the cleanser to a value suitable to the intended application on skin, where *both* an aqueous solution of pure acetic acid, or an aqueous solution of pure disodium phosphate would attack your skin.  The ratio of the two determines a *buffer capacity*, i.e., *a certain amount* of additional acid, or base added will not alter the pH value of the cleanser.  
  Just naming the ingredients of the cleanser, but without their quantities, renders it impossible to predict if the addition of a tablespoon of vinegar added to 150 mL of cleanser *already* will exhaust this capacity, or not. *If* this buffer capacity of the cleanser is exhausted, the pH value will drop.
- Regarding the "is applying of the modified skin cleanser on skin safe": **No**, *Do not* do apply this to your skin, because you may harm and (chemically) burn yourself.  The skin already is a complex system -- just think about the discern of dry / wet / fatty skin, changes by season (e.g., dry winters, humid summers), age (e.g., puberty), male / female sex in case of facial skin care; all actually under the assumption your skin were healthy.  It is not a simple layer, actually it equally is an ecosystem protecting you. So, *do not* use your altered cleanser for skin care just because you found a fancy internet page advertising a recipe.
   
  ChemSE definitley is not a replacement for a physician to consult in person, but consider just reading the abstract [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18489300) of one publication, and the publication [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4479370/) (free access) will indicate you *not* to alter a skin cleanser.

Comment: This is a very detailed and helpful response. Thank you very much!